# Stop Flash movie instead pausing it

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I have a Flash movie and stop and play button for it. When the user click on stop, it should stop. I'm using the following JavaScript code for it:

```
document.getElementById("FLVPlayer").StopPlay();
```

This stops the movie but when I click back on Play it resumes the movie instead if playing it from the start...
Can any one help?

Comment: Can you provide more info, is this your own player or something you've downloaded?  If it's yours, can you post the code to the AS function that is called by the JavaScript you mentioned?

Comment: i m just gives the .swf file by the Flash developer.Its working fine in Firefox but in IE it resumes the movie instead of playing it form the start

Answer (score 1):

`StopPlay` is a method exposed by the flash object - it is not a part of the video player - so the logic is defined by the flash plugin. Best way to achieve what you want is to expose methods from ActionScript for javascript to use via `ExternalInterface`.

I wouldn't use the flash-object command `StopPlay` for controlling the video. Even if it kinda works.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    document.getElementById("FLVPlayer").gotoAndPlay(1);