# How start/pause/stop animation object swf when click on button

Tags: jquery, flash, swfobject

**Good day.**

**I have object:**

```
<object id="EditItemFlash" class="flashPreview" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="580" height="370" loop="false" play="false">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param id="FlashColor" name="bgcolor" value="">
        <param name="movie" value="test.swf">
        <embed id="EmbedFlash" name="flash" src="test.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="580" height="370" wmode="transparent" bgcolor="" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" loop="false" play="false">
    </object>
```

***How start/pause/stop animation object when i click on button ?***

**code:**

```
$("buttontest").on("click", function(){
//start or pause or stop animation
})
```

**How make it ?**

Comment: Use the [swfobject library](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

Comment: See this thread also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620519/stop-flash-movie-instead-pausing-it